# Codeigniter getting data issue

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I've an issue with getting data from another model.

Suppose I have home page and I would like to get data from database with two different tables.

Here are my views:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?> 
<p><?php echo $item->image?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?> 
<p><?php echo $item->about ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My controller:

```
<?php

class Home extends CIF_Controller {

    public $layout = 'full';
    public $module = 'home';
    public $model = 'Sliders_model';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model($this->model);
        $this->_primary_key = $this->{$this->model}->_primary_keys[0];
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['items'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
        $this->load->view($this->module, $data);
    }


}
```

My model:

```
class Sliders_model extends CIF_model
{
    public $_table = 'sliders';
    public $_primary_keys = array('slider_id');
}
```

But I'm getting error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$about
>
> Filename: default/home.phpenter code here

Answer (score 0):

I think You hava to make sure you have field named 'about' in table.

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?> 
<p><?php echo $item->about ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i do have about in table which another controller i can fetch the data but i want the data to be on same page

Answer (score 0):

> You should enter get ( Database query ) function in your model.

```
class Sliders_model extends CIF_model
 {
   public $_table = 'sliders';
   public $_primary_keys = array('slider_id');

   public function get()
   {
     $query = $this->db->get($_table);
     return $query->result();
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this but still getting error what i'm trying to do is i have different pages but on home there's sliders and i want to insert about data on same pages do you have any solution how i can fetch these data on same controller?